# Going in same javascript if condition irrespective of value of given variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Even if the value of

> isAdmin = false

The code is not going into the condition

```
if(!isAdmin)
```

As a result, I am not getting desired output.
This is how below if called in asp.net :

```
   <span onclick="DisplayPrdWeightGrd('<%#Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>','<%# Eval("OrderId")%>','<%= Convert.ToBoolean(Utility.IsAdmin()) %>');">
```

```js
function DisplayPrdWeightGrd(index, OrderId, isAdmin) {
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../handlers/DisplayOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid + "&tk=" + $.now(),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
  if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr').length <= 1) {
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      setDataOnRow(index, v, i);
    });
  }
},
failure: function(response) {
  alert("fail");
},
error: function(response) {
  alert(response);
}
  });

  function setDataOnRow(idx, v, i) {

var totalprice;
if (v.IsGST == true) {
  totalprice = parseFloat(v.TotalPrice * (1.1)).toFixed(2);
} else {
  totalprice = parseFloat(v.TotalPrice).toFixed(2);
}

//debugger;

var obj = $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr td table:last');
if (!isAdmin) {
  $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    '<td  width="25%" >' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
    '<td  width="25%" class="center">' + v.ProductName + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.IsGST + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.Discount + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + totalprice + '</td></tr>');
} else {
  $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    '<td  width="25%" >' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
    '<td  width="25%" class="right">' + v.ProductName + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="right">' + v.IsGST + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.Discount + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + totalprice + '</td></tr>');
}
  }
```

I tried debugger, it is always going is else condition for the value **isAdmin is true or false**. Stuck here.

Comment: If I am changing to if(isAdmin) then it going in the condition and not other. response is vice-verse

Comment: check the typeof isAdmin. If it is string then it will always enter into the if condition.

Comment: ok its type is coming as string

Comment: I have posted answer to convert it boolean and then check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function DisplayPrdWeightGrd(index, OrderId, isAdmin) {       var Admin = isAdmin.toLowerCase();

  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../handlers/DisplayOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid + "&tk=" + $.now(),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
  if ($('#tableOrderDetail_' + index + ' tr').length <= 1) {
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      setDataOnRow(index, v, i);
    });
  }
},
failure: function(response) {
  alert("fail");
},
error: function(response) {
  alert(response);
}
  });

  function setDataOnRow(idx, v, i) {

var totalprice;
if (v.IsGST == true) {
  totalprice = parseFloat(v.TotalPrice * (1.1)).toFixed(2);
} else {
  totalprice = parseFloat(v.TotalPrice).toFixed(2);
}

//debugger;

var obj = $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr td table:last');
if (Admin === "false") {
  $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    '<td  width="25%" >' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
    '<td  width="25%" class="center">' + v.ProductName + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.IsGST + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.Discount + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + totalprice + '</td></tr>');
} else {
  $('#tableOrderDetail_' + idx + ' tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    '<td  width="25%" >' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
    '<td  width="25%" class="right">' + v.ProductName + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.NoOfCarton + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.ProductQuantity + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.OriginalPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="right">' + v.OrderPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="right">' + v.IsGST + '</td>' +
    '<td width="10%" class="center">' + v.Discount + '</td>' +
    '<td width="12%" class="center">' + totalprice + '</td></tr>');
}
  }
```

It solved my issue using below two lines:
1. In function

> function DisplayPrdWeightGrd(index, OrderId, isAdmin)

add

```
 var Admin = isAdmin.toLowerCase();
```

2 In function

> function setDataOnRow(idx, v, i)

add in **if condition** as

```
    if(Admin==="false")
```

Thanks for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the value of that `isAdmin` parameter as a string. So the check inside the "if" checks for the "truthy" value of the string, which is any non null/non empty value. So both the values `'True'` and `'False'` will be seen as `true`.

To solve this:

1. remove the quotes around `<%= Convert.ToBoolean(Utility.IsAdmin()) %>`
2. make sure you get `true` and `false` (lowercase!). You might need to add a `.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()`. Or (guessing that Utility.IsAdmin() returns a bool): `<%= Utility.IsAdmin() ? "true" : "false" %>`

Comment: using ur point of removing quote , does not call the DisplayPrdWeightGrd at all

Comment: @HinaKhuman  Did it write out `True` (capital T) or `true` (lowercase)? (it should be lowercase) What is actually in the generated html/javascript? Any errors in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var isAdmin = Boolean(isAdmin);
```

then check if-else condition.

```
if(!isAdmin)
```

Comment: Still the same situation it is not going inside  If(!isAdmin) condition block

Comment: @HinaKhuman what's the output of console.log(typeof isAdmin, isAdmin) after the conversion.

Comment: var Admin = typeof(isAdmin); gives me string type

Comment: var isAdmin = Boolean(isAdmin); console.log(typeof isAdmin, isAdmin); now what is consoled? copy paste the same line as in comment.

Comment: in both the case like Saler or Admin it giving *true* value.   var Admin = Boolean(isAdmin);
            alert(Admin);

Comment: alert(isAdmin) is giving *true* or *false* depending on *Admin* or *Saler* .But var Admin = Boolean(isAdmin);  is giving true in both cases

Answer (score 0):

The `isAdmin` only exists inside your ajax call, thus your `setDataOnRow` function will not recognize it hence always go to the  `else`

Comment: No it does go inside *setDataOnRow*. I set alert inside that function.alert gives the exact value